# Old switch is missing a wire connection

Tags: switch, house

[image]There are two light fixtures in the bathroom.  Switch on the left works to switch the light fixture on wall (that is OK).  I am confused how the right switch should be wired to control the ceiling light)? There was only a blue wire connected to the right switch.  What wire should I jumper to the other connection at the switch?

I have a photo but do not know how to add to post

Comment: To post a photo, edit your message and use the "mountain landscape" icon at the top of the edit box.

Comment: If you can even leave a link to the photo, it is likely someone could help you edit it in to the post.

Comment: I see a wire nut at the bottom of the box with 3 red wires. One seems to go to the switch on the left, one seems to go out the top of the box, where does the 3rd one go?

Comment: Great question.  I assume (but not sure) that the red wire comes in from the circuit breaker panel that is just on the other side of the wall to the right of the switches.  My overall assumption is that I need a hot wire routed to the switch on the right side (maybe the red conductor is HOT?).   Thanks

Comment: My plan is to use my fluke meter to verify the red wire is hot.  And verify the resistance of the wires routed to the ceiling light (with the ceiling bulb installed and circuit breaker power off).

Comment: Looking at the photos a little closer.  I am not sure what the black wire is coming from the left side and routing back up to the conduit that routes to the  wall light fixture?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to ad a hot wire to the switch. The most likely source would be the 3 red wires with the wire nut.

Check that those red wires are constant hot from the breaker.

Turn the breaker off.

Add a "pigtail" wire from the 3 red to the other screw on the switch.

With 4 wires to twist together, you should get a larger wire nut. In the U.S. **red** is the size most used for 4 #12 wires.

Comment: Good information.   Thanks I found  a small length of 12 awg red wire and red size wire nuts at Home Depot .

Comment: Light switch’s are now working great.  Thanks for the help, it was spot on. 

Verified red wires were hot.  Installed the new red jumper wire to the switch, and installed new red wire nut to accept the 4x12 awg wires.  Also installed new switch (it was very old).  

Eventually determined light fixture was also bad (degraded wire to bulb connection).  This was likely why someone removed wire and disabled switch.

Comment: Good to hear....please  click on the check mark to accept my answer as the one that answered your question.